# How to include data array in on chart.js line chart

Tags: php, arrays, chart.js

I have set up the following code to get array data[]; but I don't know how to put those array in chart.js line code

`$data[]        = array(substr($row['CHANGE_DATE'], 5), $lastMax, $lastMin);`

I want to draw a line chat with X-axis as CHANGE_DATE, Y-axis: $lastMax, $lastMin

---

Chart.js code

```
  <script>
        // line chart data
        var buyerData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
            datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
                strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
                pointColor : "#fff",
                pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
                data : [203,156,99,251,305,247]
            }
        ]
        }
        // get line chart canvas
        var buyers = document.getElementById('buyers').getContext('2d');
        // draw line chart
        new Chart(buyers).Line(buyerData);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984772/chart-js-data-array-using-php-mysql-how-to-define-datasource-from-json-array

Comment: what exactly are you trying to plot? your `js` code has 6 points set for data, and your php array appears to have the first value as a date, and the second 2 values as data points. you have 6 labels, which implies 6 different data sets. So I really have no idea what you are trying plot. Without any code, can you describe the chart you are trying to create?

Comment: Hello, i want to replace (1)["January","February","March","April","May","June"] with $row['CHANGE_DATE'];  (2)[203,156,99,251,305,247] with $lastMin, and $lastMax

Comment: no body can help?  http://www.domlai.com